# Should I use indexes for a single row table with 100+ columns that is constantly updated?

Tags: mysql

I realize this is a strange architecture, but each row in the table represents a 'game table', and so far there is only one table. The table has many columns on it, representing things such as chips at each seat, cards at each seat (which must remain persistent even if players switch, there's many reasons I set it up like this).

Here is my question: Since this single row in the table is updated ALL the time (ie: every time a SELECT query is called, the table will almost always have different values due to the large number of UPDATES on this single row) would using an INDEX provide any benefit anywhere?

Comment: If it will always have a single row, an index would only add overhead, and reduce performance.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for thanks